# Integral of the indicator function of a measurable set with respect to the product measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let us say that $E$ is a measurable set with respect to the product measure $\mu \times \nu$ on $X \times Y$.

My professor uses the following,

$$\int_{X \times Y} \chi_{E}(x,y) d( \mu \times \nu) = \mu(E)\nu(E)$$

This seems intuitively correct but I cannot find a theorem/lemma stating it. Also, I am not entirely sure how to prove it or if I am missing any assumptions.

Any pointer in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: That is simply false. $\mu(E)$ and $\nu(E)$are not even defined ($E \subset X\times Y$). What is true is that if $E =A \times B$ with $A \subset X, B \subset Y$ measurable, then the integral is equal to $\mu(A)\nu(B)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This in general is not correct. For an indicator function, $\chi_E$ which is $1$ on $E$ and $0$ elsewhere, $\int_{X\times Y}\chi_{E}(x,y)d(\mu\times\nu)=(\mu\times\nu)(E)$. Only if $E=A\times B$ with $A\in\Sigma_X$ and $B\in\Sigma_Y$ will $(\mu\times\nu)(E)=\mu(E)\nu(E)$. I'm assuming you mean $\mu(E)$ and $\nu(E)$ to be the measures of the projections of $E$ onto $X$ and $Y$.

EDIT: Remember that the product sigma algebra is generated by rectangular sets, and contains many more measurable sets.